# dir="rtl" and dir="ltr" is not working on Android 4.4, 5.1 and 6.0 Email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, email-template, html5, css3

dir="rtl" and dir="ltr" is not working on Android 4.4, 5.1 and 6.0 Email

Any ideas on how to fix this issue?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be best giving some example of your code, but for reference in HTML5, the dir attribute can be used on any HTML element (it will validate on any HTML element. However, it is not necessarily useful).

In HTML 4.01, the dir attribute cannot be used with:

`<base>, <br>, <frame>, <frameset>, <hr>, <iframe>, <param>, and <script>.`

If you are using HTML5 in your email then it wouldn't be recommended as its not always compatible with every email client so you may experience rendering issues  of reliant on HTML5. With email design you are best using old html school html techniques.

If you can give example of your html then I might be able to help further.